# Angular mat-grid-list does not fit contents as expected

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I want a `mat-grid-list` that properly fits the contents of the mat-card.  I expected to get equally spaced columns.  4 cards per row.  I get a jumbled mess.  If I replace the contents of `mat-card` with plain text then it looks good.  How can I display `mat-form-fields` properly in such a fashion?

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="Active">
    <mat-grid-list cols="4" rowHeight="100px" gutterSize="50px">
      <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let number of [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]">
        <mat-card>
          <div class="example-container">
            <mat-form-field>
              <input matInput placeholder="Input">
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field>
              <textarea matInput placeholder="Textarea"></textarea>
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field>
              <mat-select placeholder="Select">
                <mat-option value="option">Option</mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
        </mat-card>
      </mat-grid-tile>
    </mat-grid-list>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

I didn't add any extra/custom CSS to the test.component.

Note, this does look OK if you have expand it out fully on a 4K monitor.  The alignment is off, but at least no content is completely lost here.  It's the lesser...2k or 3/4 screen on 4k where it starts trimming content.

Do I need to switch to a custom flexbox for this?

This is my **target** look:  (Ideally the number of columns would shift automatically with smaller resolution)

[image]

[stackblitz](https://angular-rtdavp.stackblitz.io)

Comment: Your stackblitz is not loading.

Comment: I tested it as well, unable to load your stackblitz. Please update that.

Comment: I didn't understand you completely yet. What layout do you wish? Always 4 cards in one row, but now two 2 rows filled with total 8 cards and the layout shell never change, just the size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your existing stackblitz, you can make these 2 changes to get what you need

replace your **card-overview-example.css** with:

```
.mat-card { display:inline-block; max-width:200px; min-width:100px; margin:0 10px; }
```

replace your **card-overview-example.html** with:

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="Active">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let number of [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]">
        <mat-card >
          <h2>Some Name</h2>
          <div class="example-container">
            <mat-form-field>
              <input matInput placeholder="Input">
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field>
              <textarea matInput placeholder="Textarea"></textarea>
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field>
              <mat-select placeholder="Select">
                <mat-option value="option">Option</mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
        </mat-card>
      </ng-container>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: Note I changed margin to 10px all around.  `.mat-card { display:inline-block; max-width:200px; min-width:100px; margin:10px 10px 10px 10px; }`

Comment: it is your call sir; just using `margin:10px 10px` also accomplishes the same while saving a few KBs :)